# How To Hide Option From Select DropDown If Same Id Exist In Both Table

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I'm using PHP based on MVC structure, i have 2 tables `sale` & `receipt`, when a user want to make `receipt` he/she will select dropdown option, `Sale No.` coming from `DB` `sale` table, which has a value of `sale_id`, so that user make `recept` on behalf of `sale`, and `sale_id` store in `receipt` table, i want to achieve that if `sale_id` exist in `receipt` table, hide that option from Select DropDown Options.

Like in Below Images, i have `3 sale` record and `1 receipt` record, `receipt` record contains `sale_id`, i want to hide that `Sale No.` from select dropdown option.

**SALE TABLE**
[image]

**RECEIPT TABLE**
[image]

**Select Option In `Receipt`**

```html
<select class="form-control" id="sale_id" name="sale_id">
  <option disabled selected value="">Select One</option>
  <?php foreach($sales as $sale): ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $sale['sale_id']; ?>" <?php echo ($sale_id==$ sale[ 'sale_id']? 'selected="selected"': ''); ?>>
    <?php echo $sale['sale_no']; ?>&nbsp;=>&nbsp;
    <?php echo $sale['customer_name']; ?>
  </option>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

**My Receipt Controller : That How I'm getting Data From Sale Table In My DropDown Option**

```html
$this->model['sale'] = $this->load->model('sale/sale');
$this->data['sales'] = $this->model['sale']->getRows();
```

**My Receipt Model**

```html
class ModelTransactionReceipt extends HModel {

    protected function getTable() {
        return 'receipt';
    }

    protected function getView() {
        return 'vw_receipt';
    }

    public function getMaxReceiptNo(){
        $sql = "SELECT MAX(receipt_no) as max_no FROM `receipt`";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        $record = $query->row;

        if(empty($record['max_no'])) {
            $max_no =  1;
        } else {
            $max_no =  $record['max_no']+1;
        }

        return $max_no;
    }
        public function getRemainingSale() {
           $sql = "SELECT sale_id";
           $sql = " FROM `sale`";
           $sql = " WHERE  sale_id NOT IN (SELECT sale_id FROM `receipt`)";

           $query = $this->db->query($sql);
           $record = $query->row;
    }

}
```

Comment: Upload your model as wel . We have to upload the answer with your model query

Comment: @MD.JubairMizan Model Updated....

Comment: Man where is your getRows() on model?

Comment: @MD.JubairMizan Its in `HModel`

Comment: You can get the result rows with only the records which not exists in receipt table by using left join or right join and display those in select box

Comment: @Naveen I' doing something like this -> See Updated Answer In My Model

Comment: where is your sales model and why you are adding ```getRemainingSale()``` in receipt model ?
change the model from ```sale/sale``` to ```receipt``` and then change ```getRows()``` to ```getRemainingSale()```.

Comment: @Naveen yeah I've done it... Thanks

Comment: is it working fine as expected ?

Comment: @Yeah Brother..... :)

Answer (score 0):

I've made this function in my `Sale Model`:

```html
    public function getRemainingSale() {
        $sql = "SELECT `sale_id`,";
        $sql .= " `sale_no`,";
        $sql .= " `customer_name`,";
        $sql .= " `sale_amount`";
        $sql .= " FROM   sale";
        $sql .= " WHERE  sale_id NOT IN (SELECT sale_id FROM `receipt`)";

        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        $record = $query->rows;
        return $record;
    }
```

And call `Sale Model` with that function in `receipt controller`:

```html
        $this->model['sale'] = $this->load->model('sale/sale');
        $this->data['sales'] = $this->model['sale']->getRemainingSale();
//        d($this->data['sales'],true);
```